# Can't get JSON data with retrofit 2

Tags: java, retrofit2

I know this is not the first time someone asking about this problem but with Retrofit2 I can't find the right solution to my problem. I followed a online tutorial and it worked just fine. When I applied same code to my own endpoint i get this exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ I don't know how to solve this.
I have JSON data like this

> [
>       {
>           "id_toko": "3",
>           "nama_toko": "Toko Ajib",
>           "pesan_toko": "Diskon Gan !!"
>       } ]

and like this

> [
>       {
>           "id_device": "1",
>           "nama_device": "Samsung Galaxy A5",
>           "jenis_device": "Android"
>       } ]

I want to parse them to my app, this is my service API

```
public interface ServiceApi {

    @GET("show2.php")
        Call<List<DataRepo>> toko(

    );

    @GET("show1.php")
        Call<DataSearch> searching(

    );
}
```

And here my model :

```
public class DataRepo {

    @SerializedName("id_toko")
    int id_toko;

    @SerializedName("nama_toko")
    String nama_toko;

    @SerializedName("pesan_toko")
    String pesan_toko;

    public int getId_toko() {
        return id_toko;
    }

    public String getNama_toko() {
        return nama_toko;
    }

    public String getPesan_toko() {
        return pesan_toko;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DataSearch {

    @SerializedName("items")
    List<Item> items;

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Item {

    @SerializedName("id_device")
    int id_device;

    @SerializedName("nama_device")
    String nama_device;


    @SerializedName("jenis_device")
    String jenis_device;

    public int getId_device() {
        return id_device;
    }

    public String getNama_device() {
        return nama_device;
    }


    public String getJenis_device() {
        return jenis_device;
    }
}
```

My main method

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceApi client = ClientApi.createService(ServiceApi.class);

        Call<List<DataRepo>> call = client.toko();
        Call<DataSearch> call1 = client.searching();

        List<DataRepo> toko = null;
        DataSearch searches = null;
        List<Item> items = null;
        try {
            toko = call.execute().body();
            searches = call1.execute().body();
            for (DataRepo tokos : toko) {
                System.out.println(tokos.getNama_toko() + " (" + tokos.getPesan_toko() + ")");
            }

            System.out.println();

            items = searches.getItems();
            for (Item item : items){
                System.out.println(item.getNama_device() + ", Jenis: " + item.getJenis_device());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

BUt i cant get the JSON data, all i have in error log is

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this model class for your first json

```
public class JsonItems{

@SerializedName("id_toko")
@Expose
private String idToko;
@SerializedName("nama_toko")
@Expose
private String namaToko;
@SerializedName("pesan_toko")
@Expose
private String pesanToko;

public String getIdToko() {
return idToko;
}

public void setIdToko(String idToko) {
this.idToko = idToko;
}

public String getNamaToko() {
return namaToko;
}

public void setNamaToko(String namaToko) {
this.namaToko = namaToko;
}

public String getPesanToko() {
return pesanToko;
}

public void setPesanToko(String pesanToko) {
this.pesanToko = pesanToko;
}

}
```

and the following method for your network call using retrofit 2

```
private void loadJSON() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("your BASE_URL")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    BankInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<List<JsonItems>> call = request.getToken();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<JsonItems>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<JsonItems>> call, Response<List<JsonItems>> response) {
            List<JsonItems> jsonItems= response.body();
            String token = jsonItems.get(0).getIdToko();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<JsonItems>> call, Throwable t) {
            showToast("No Internet Connection");
        }


    });

}
```

and the following for specifying endpoints

```
public interface BankInterface {

@GET("your endpoint")
Call<List<JsonItems>> getToken();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, one more question, is there a method to store my json data into variable and use it in another function ?

Comment: yes you can, save it to shared pref like this>> Gson gson = new Gson();
               String  json = gson.toJson(jsonItems);

Comment: store this data to shared preference and use in whichever funtion you want